# understanding this task 'Summing'

Tags: java, sum

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what this assignment is asking me to do. I'm an absolute beginner, a few weeks of learning Java/programming in general, and this is very hard for me. So apologies for not being very specific in the title.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain to me, perhaps with a bit of sample code for one example (I'm not asking people to do the task for me, I just find it easier to understand that way) so I can get the idea of what to do.

Thank you.

Specification of Summing:

This programs takes input from the command line.

```
The first input is K, an integer, followed by an arbitrary number a_1, ..., a_N of floating-point numbers.

If K=0, then N is output.

If K > 0, then the a_i are grouped in groups of size K, inside the groups the numbers are multiplied, and all the products are added, yielding the output.
If K < 0, then the summation sums up the reciprocal values of the products.
In the special case K=1 the output thus is a_1 + ... + a_N.
In the case K=-1 the output is 1/a_1 + ... + 1/a_N.

There are two error cases:
If no command-line argument is given, then error-code 1 is to be returned.
If K < 0, and one of a_i = 0, then error-code 2 is to be returned.
In both cases there must be no output.
The return-code of a program is set via System.exit(code);
```

Note that the return-code of a program is obtained on the command line via echo $?.
There must never be any other output. Also no additional spaces or line breaks are allowed.

Here are the examples for the case of no errors:  http://pastebin.com/F2uz262v

Comment: you should write a console application which takes an input from it and executes a number of Java statements. After the program finished it returns the exit code to the console.

Comment: In fairness the specification is pretty poorly written IMO. Anyways, you just need to write a few if/else statements (like `if (K > 0)`) do whatever calculation they want you to do, and then presumably print that onto the console using `System.out.println`.

Comment: This questions is more appropiate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The pseudocode describes a program's logic virtually step by step. The main challenge is understanding each sentence (or component of the program, like the variable K) and implementing it faithfully in java syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find the command line arguments here:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
                            // ^ these are the command line arguments
```

So to get K,

```
int K = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

but actually that's not how you should write it, because this is Java and Java variables should start with a lower case letter.

```
int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

First let's deal with the case where k=0. We have to test if k is 0:

```
if(k == 0) {
```

and if it is, then N is the number of additional arguments, which is

```
  int numberOfAdditionalArguments = args.length - 1;
```

and then we print it (with no line breaks afterwards, like it says!)

```
  System.out.print(numberOfAdditionalArguments);
```

then we close the } block

```
}
```

I think that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you! I understand this now. Now its onto the hard part... how do I group the inputs into groups of K?

Comment: so.. example input: 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Solution: (1*2*3) + (4*5*6) + (7*8) 

A point in the right direction would be really appreciated!

Comment: For that you will need to loop over the `args` from `1` to `args.length - 1`. You can either do it using 2 loops, one of them nested inside the other, or using 1 single loop, and a counter. Use whichever way makes most sense to you.